# How can I make Backbone.js handle dropped connections?

Tags: backbone.js, local-storage

I'm working on a mobile web app, where it is important to be able to continue working in offline mode if the connection is dropped, and have the data be sent whenever the connection is back up.

I'm experimenting with saving the object to LocalStorage on the error event, and deleting it from LocalStorage on the sync event. That seems to work fine, but where should I load it?

So far, I have overloaded Collection.fetch, to merge in the LocalStorage models and re-save them, but it feels kind of wonky.

Should I periodically try to re-sync the models until it succeeds?

The implementation:

https://gist.github.com/geon/7890291

Comment: take a look at this http://github.hubspot.com/offline/docs/welcome/  you can capture the online/offline events, and use localstorage/server accordingly.

Comment: Offline.js looks promising, but not very customizable. Also It doesn't mention saving data to localstorage? I'll have to run some experiments.